# Updating variable after AJAX call in jquery

Tags: forms, jquery, django-forms

I want to create a page whether the user makes a selection on a (Django ModelChoice) form and this then results in an Ajax update of another form which may then trigger an additional Ajax update. My rather rudimentary javascript skills are not up to the task!

The problem is that I cannot correctly read the value of the updated form - it is always one step behind where I think it should be.  In the simplified example below, it is as if Jquery is calculating the value of second_var at the same time as first_var (i.e before I have updated it with the Ajax call).  If I keep switching between two options in #id_first_metric, second_var will update but it is always pointing to the value of #id_second_metric before the last update.

How can I get second_var to correctly contain its newly updated value?

```
function first_function(first_var){
    console.log('first var:' + first_var);
    //    correctly states the value of first var
    var update_url = '/ajax/update_second_metric/first_var';
    $('#id_second_metric').load(update_url);

$('#first_metric_selector').change(function () {
    var first_var = $('#id_first_metric').val();
    first_function(first_var);
    $('#second_metric_selector').change();
});

$('#second_metric_selector').change(function () {
    var second_var = $('#id_second_metric').val();
    console.log('second var' + second_var);
    //  fails to detect the new value of second var created by the first
    //  AJAX call
});
```

ANSWER

```
function first_function(first_var){
    console.log('first var:' + first_var);
    //    correctly states the value of first var
    var update_url = '/ajax/update_second_metric/';
    $('#id_second_metric').load(update_url, function(){
        $('#second_metric_selector').change();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"$('#id_second_metric').load(update_url)" happens asynchronously. There is no guarantee that  "$('#second_metric_selector').change()" will be called before the "$('#id_second_metric').load(update_url)" finishes.

You can use callback function provided by load to guarantee the order. See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks @Biswanath, that solved the problem.  I've spelled out the solution above for posterity..